# Прикрепить видео на страницу электронной книги

Tags: ebook, html, видео, exe

Можно ли написать книгу на html и преобразовать ее с помощью определенных программ в exe файл, так чтобы на ее страницах можно было разместить видео ролики. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вполне только обьем книги будет бешенный.

Comment: и как это сделать? Какую лучше программу использовать? Или хотя бы как сделать ссылку на скачивание с этой книги видео файла? В браузере все работает, а когда конвертирую в exe в книге перестает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я сам писал программу браузер а уже в сам екзешник в ресурсы было вшито и видео и текст HTML, готовыми программами не пользовался подсказать не могу.